# Istream consume at most N whitespace characters

Tags: c++, iostream, istream

Is it possible to tell a std::istream to only consume a fixed number (namely, 1) of whitespace characters when applying the operator>>? I have a string I'd like to parse into parameters, but some of the parameters are empty, which is causing subsequent calls to operator>> to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`std::noskipws`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/) :

```
std::cin >> std::noskipws;
char ws;
std::string firstField, secondField, thirdField;
std::cin >> firstField >> ws >> secondField >> ws >> thirdField;
```

Or, you could slurp the entire line into a string (see `std::getline`), and then [split it with Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp).